# `No corda-webserver JAR found.` error when deploying Corda nodes

Tags: corda

In Corda 3, I am switching my Corda nodes from using the deprecated built-in webserver to using my own Spring Webserver.

In the project's `build.gradle` file, I have removed the dependency on the Corda webserver (`cordaRuntime "$corda_release_group:corda-webserver:$corda_release_version"`).

However, when I run `deployNodes`, I get the following error:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':deployNodes'.
> No corda-webserver JAR found. Have you deployed the Corda project to Maven? Looked for "corda-webserver-3.1-corda.jar"
```

Why is `deployNodes` looking for the Corda webserver when I've removed the dependency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`deployNodes` will automatically look for the Corda webserver JAR if one or more of the nodes have a web port (e.g. `webPort 10007`).

Once you remove these web ports, the `deployNodes` task will execute normally.

Answer (score 4):

That is probably because you are defining webPort without having the webserver module installed.

To fix please ensure that you add the following into **build.gradle** file and under Corda dependencies.

```
cordaRuntime "$corda_release_group:corda-webserver:$corda_release_version"
cordaCompile "$corda_release_group:corda-webserver-impl:$corda_release_version"
```

This will install the webserver for your project.
*Rebuild

Comment: Or remove the `webPort` entries if you don't want to use the built-in webserver.

Comment: Yes that will eliminate the error as well but of course then, the webservers will not be spawned.